Nonnegativity of a Summed Gaussian Difference Series for 1D Dirichlet Heat Kernel
Consider:
$$G(z;\alpha) = e^{-\alpha z^2}$$
Take $x,y \in [0,1]$. Is it possible to show that:
$$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} G(x-y+2n; \alpha) - G(x+y + 2n; \alpha) \geq 0$$
for all $\alpha > 0$? If we restrict to $n \in \mathbb N$, the result is clear. However, I do not know how to properly deal with the $n < 0$ terms...
Note:
The solution to the heat equation with initial condition $u(x,0) = f(x) \geq 0$ on a rod of length $L$ and Dirichlet boundary conditions gives us:
\begin{align}
u(x,t) = \int_0^L f(y) K_t(x,y) \, dy
\end{align}
for
\begin{align}
K_t(x,y) \sim \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} 
\left(  \exp \left(-\frac{(x-y+2nL)^2 L^2}{4 \kappa \pi^2 t}\right) -  \exp \left(-\frac{(x+y+2nL)^2 L^2}{4 \kappa \pi^2 t}\right)\right).
\end{align}
This expression can be obtained by applying separation of variables --> Poisson Summation Formula. I was hoping this expression would make the maximum principle immediately apparent in the expression of the solution, but it must require an additional step to prove non-negativity.
